# Как выбрать начальную тету в простой линейной регрессии?

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение

У меня есть продажи товаров с января 2013 года по октябрь 2015 года. Я просто хочу спрогнозировать общий объем продаж на следующий месяц. Просто для того, чтобы научиться, я хотел бы превратить его в многократную регрессионную модель, закодированную с нуля, без каких-либо библиотек. Пока что мне удалось получить бета-версии, но я не знаю, как получить прогноз на следующий месяц.

Вот исторические данные ежемесячных продаж с января 2013 года по октябрь 2015 года,

Ниже приведены исторические данные ежемесячных продаж с января 2013 года по октябрь 2015 года, `ts`:

```
date_block_num
0     131479.0
1     128090.0
2     147142.0
3     107190.0
4     106970.0
5     125381.0
6     116966.0
7     125291.0
8     133332.0
9     127541.0
10    130009.0
11    183342.0
12    116899.0
13    109687.0
14    115297.0
15     96556.0
16     97790.0
17     97429.0
18     91280.0
19    102721.0
20     99208.0
21    107422.0
22    117845.0
23    168755.0
24    110971.0
25     84198.0
26     82014.0
27     77827.0
28     72295.0
29     64114.0
30     63187.0
31     66079.0
32     72843.0
33     71056.0
```

Я пытался сделать простую линейную регрессию:

[image: $$y_t = \alpha + \beta x_t +\varepsilon$$]

Сначала я попытался оценить *alpha* и *beta*, а затем использовал `predict(alpha,beta,34)`. Так я и сделал:

```
import random

def predict(alpha, beta, x_i):
  return alpha+ beta * x_i

def error(alpha, beta, x_i, y_i):
  """the error from predicting beta * x_i + alpha
  when the actual value is y_i"""
  return y_i - predict(alpha, beta, x_i)

def sum_of_squarred_errors(alpha, beta, x, y):
  return sum(errors(alpha, beta, x_i, y_i)**2
             for x_i, y_i in zip(x,y))
  
def correlation(x,y):
  stdev_x = standard_deviation(x)
  stdev_y = standard_deviation(y)
  if stdev_x > 0 and stdev_y >0:
    return covariance(x,y)/ stdev_x/ stdev_y
  else:
    return 0

def squared_error(x_i, y_i, theta):
  alpha, beta = theta
  return error(alpha, beta, x_i, y_i) ** 2

def squared_error_gradient(x_i, y_i, theta):
  alpha, beta = theta
  return [-2 * error(alpha, beta, x_i, y_i),
          -2 * error(alpha, beta, x_i, y_i) * x_i]

def in_random_order(data):
  """generator that returns the elements if data in random order"""
  indexes = [i for i, _ in enumerate(data)] # create a list of indexes
  random.shuffle(indexes) # suffle them
  for i in indexes:
    yield data[i]

def scalar_multiply(c, v):
    """c is a number, v is a vector"""
    return [c*v_i for v_i in v]

def minimize_stochastic(target_fn, gradient_fn, x,y, theta_0, alpha_0=0.01):
  print("x: ", x, "\ny: ",y.tolist())
  data = zip(x,y)
  theta = theta_0  #initial guess
  alpha = alpha_0  # initial step size
  min_theta, min_value = None, float('inf') # the minimum so far
  iterations_with_no_improvment = 0

  # if we ever go 100 iterations with no improvment, stop
  while iterations_with_no_improvment < 100:
    value = sum(target_fn(x_i, y_i, theta) for x_i, y_i in data)
    # print("value: ", value)

    if value < min_value:
      # if we've found a new minimum, remember it
      # and go back to the original step size
      min_theta, min_value = theta, value
      iterations_with_no_improvment = 0
      alpha = alpha_0
    else:
      # otherwise we're not improving, so try shrinking the step size
      iterations_with_no_improvment +=1
      alpha *=0.9

    # and take a gradient step for each of the data points
    for x_i, y_i in in_random_order(data):
      gradient_i = gradient_fn(x_i, y_i, theta)
      theta = vector_substract(theta, scalar_multiply(alpha, gradient_i))
  return min_theta

# choose random value to start
random.seed(0)
theta = [random.random(), random.random()]

alpha, beta = minimize_stochastic(squared_error,
                                  squared_error_gradient, ts.index.values,
                                  ts.values,
                                  theta,
                                  0.001)

print("alpha: ", alpha, "beta: ", beta)
```

Но у него супернизкие альфа и бета:

```
alpha:  0.8444218515250481 beta:  0.7579544029403025
```

Таким образом, общий объем продаж за 34 (ноябрь 2015 года): 26,614871551495334 что выглядит невозможным по сравнению с 33 (октябрь 2015 г.): 71056,0

Так я испортил алгоритм линейной регрессии? Я думаю, что мои случайные значения для начала, возможно, слишком низкие:

```
theta = [random.random(), random.random()]
```

Тем не менее, они должны увеличиваться в любом случае до тех пор, пока больше нет входа, не так ли?

Так как же выбрать исходные теории для простой линейной регрессии?

Comment: А не слишком ли широко вы шагаете по градиенту? -2 не многовато? Не факт, что здесь проблема, просто бросилось в глаза.

Comment: А вообще для time series простая регрессия точно не взлетит. У вас явный спад в январе, нужно выделять месяц года как фичу, это как минимум. Просто из сквозного номера месяца модель ничего не поймёт. Ну и третий год у вас весь год спад, значит год году рознь, надо и год выделять как фичу отдельно.

Comment: NameError: name 'in_random_order' is not defined

Comment: NameError: name 'scalar_multiply' is not defined

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, это так. Прости меня за то, что я забыл, дорогой друг. Я только что узнал о том, чего не хватает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте по порядку.

Во-первых, одномерная линейная модель для ваших данных, в которых явно просматривается сезонная составляющая, вряд-ли будет хорошим решением.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во-вторых, если вы хотите использовать именно одномерную линейную регрессию, и хотите ее написать вручную, без привлечения сторонних модулей, то надо использовать "классику жанра" и искать уравнения в явном виде

```
numerator=np.sum((x-np.mean(x))*(y-np.mean(y)))
denominator=np.sum((x-np.mean(x))**2)
b1=numerator/denominator
b0=np.mean(y)-b1*np.mean(x)
plt.plot(x,y,c='b')
x=np.arange(1,40)
y_pred=b0+b1*x
plt.plot(x,y_pred,c='r')
```

Если бы мне хотелось потренировать навыки самостоятельного программирования алгоритмов, то я бы начал, например, с предсказания с помощью скользящего среднего или экспоненциального сглаживания. Обе пишутся вручную достаточно просто.

Идея запускать градиентный поиск для данной задачи - немного сомнительна.
Если вам поможет, то значения коэффициентов b0 и b1 для вашего примера равны
141311.93048128343 и -1943.5288006111537 соответственно.

P.S. Что такое "многократная регрессионная модель" я, увы, не знаю. Расшифруйте пожалуйста сей термин.

Comment: Какая-нибудь авторегрессия может имелась в виду? )

Comment: @CrazyElf не знаю, сначала я подумал про экспоненциальное сглаживание, но формула явно не та.  А так, конечно авторегрессионная модель должна быть, SARIMA, если повезет -  то с нулевыми i и m параметрами.

Comment: @passant Большое спасибо за ваше предложение. Я считаю, что использование «классики жанра» и поиск уравнений в явном виде - лучшее решение для одномерной линейной регрессии. Как вы думаете, можно ли отремонтировать мою модель в любом случае или она действительно испорчена?

Comment: Что значит "испорчена". Я ваш код  честно говоря не разбирал подробно, но фрагменты полностью (с точностью до имени переменной) совпадающие с моим примером нашел. Вот и отбросьте все лишнее, что "портит".  А хотите что-то добавить "от себя" -  добавляйте, но потом, когда убедитесь, что "ядро" работает правильно.